# How can I make this WHERE NOT EXISTS query more efficient

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly, Tables

**Surveys**

```
CREATE TABLE `surveys` (
 `survey_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `survey_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`survey_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


INSERT INTO `surveys` (`survey_id`, `survey_name`) VALUES
(1, 's1'),
(2, 's2');
```

**Survey_responses**

```
CREATE TABLE `survey_responses` (
 `sr_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sr_text` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `sr_tq_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `sr_st_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `sr_su_uid` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`sr_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `survey_responses` (`sr_id`, `sr_text`, `sr_tq_id`, `sr_st_id`, `sr_su_uid`) VALUES
(1, 'a', 3, 2, 3),
(2, 'b', 4, 2, 3);
```

**Survey_topics**

```
CREATE TABLE `survey_topics` (
 `st_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `st_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `st_survey_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`st_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

  INSERT INTO `survey_topics` (`st_id`, `st_name`, `st_survey_id`) VALUES
(1, 't1', 1),
(2, 't2', 1),
(3, 't3', 1),
(4, 't4', 2),
(5, 't5', 2),
(6, 't6', 2);
```

**Survey_users**

```
CREATE TABLE `survey_users` (
 `su_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `su_s_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `su_uid` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`su_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `survey_users` (`su_id`, `su_s_id`, `su_uid`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 2, 2);
```

**topic_questions**

```
CREATE TABLE `topic_questions` (
 `tq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tq_text` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `tq_st_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`tq_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `topic_questions` (`tq_id`, `tq_text`, `tq_st_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'q1', 1),
    (2, 'q2', 1),
    (3, 'q3', 2),
    (4, 'q4', 2);
```

**Users**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `u_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `users` (`u_id`, `uname`) VALUES
(1, 'Bob'),
(2, 'Gary');
```

Now the query,

```
 SELECT * FROM `surveys`
INNER JOIN survey_users ON survey_users.su_s_id = surveys.survey_id
INNER JOIN survey_topics ON survey_topics.st_survey_id = surveys.survey_id
INNER JOIN topic_questions ON survey_topics.st_id = topic_questions.tq_st_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM survey_responses a WHERE a.sr_tq_id = topic_questions.tq_id AND a.sr_st_id = survey_topics.st_id AND a.sr_su_uid = survey_users.su_uid
    )
```

Basically I am trying to get a list of surveys where even one user has missed a survey response even if that is for only 1 question for only 1 topic.

This query works well however is extremely slow on a database with thousands of surveys, topics, users , questions and responses.

Please can someone provide an query of doing this that will be quicker, I have read that using left join instead of WHERE NOT EXISTS is more efficient?

Appreciate the help guys, I have indexes in the actual database, this example does not have any indexes.

Thanks.

Comment: A good start would be to index the columns you use in your SELECT statement, so for example, indexing `sr_tq_id` would probably help.

Comment: An index in the table `survey_responses` on the fields `sr_tq_id`, `sr_st_id`, `sr_su_uid` should help

Comment: I'd suggest reading http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql to determine which columns to index in your tables. Using MySQL's `EXPLAIN` should help determine where bottlenecks may be too.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help but I was hoping for a restructure of the query rather than adding an index.  I have indexes in the actual db that are not on this example. I have read that using joins might be more efficient but I am not too sure how to achieve this?

Comment: add a combined index on `sr_tq_id`, `sr_st_id`, `sr_su_uid`  and use onoly SELECT 1 instead pf *

Comment: When doing `NOT EXISTS ( select * ....)` or  `NOT EXISTS ( select 1 ....)` will be optimized by MySQL 8+, and does not make a difference... (I do not knot how that was before MySQL 8)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the other variants of [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) where performance can differ:

**LEFT JOIN / NULL**

```sql
...
LEFT JOIN survey_responses sr 
  ON  sr.sr_tq_id  = topic_questions.tq_id 
  AND sr.sr_st_id  = survey_topics.st_id
  AND sr.sr_su_uid = survey_users.su_uid

WHERE sr.sr_tq_id  IS NULL
  AND sr.sr_st_id  IS NULL
  AND sr.sr_su_uid IS NULL
```

**NOT IN** *(MySQL appears to support multi-column IN)*

```
...
WHERE (topic_questions.tq_id, survey_topics.st_id, survey_users.su_uid) 
NOT IN (
    SELECT a.sr_tq_id​, a.sr_st_id, a.sr_su_uid ​
    FROM survey_responses
)
```

**NOT IN** *(using CTE due to multiple columns)*

```sql
WITH sub AS (
  SELECT a.sr_tq_id​, a.sr_st_id, a.sr_su_uid 
  ​FROM survey_responses
)

SELECT
...
WHERE topic_questions.tq_id NOT IN (SELECT a.str_tq_id FROM sub)
  AND survey_topics.st_id   NOT IN (SELECT a.sr_st_id  FROM sub)
  AND survey_users.su_uid ​  NOT IN (SELECT a.sr_su_uid FROM sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the topic_questions table and include columns for the questions in that table. You can then check for NULLs in these columns to determine the questions users haven't answered.

Also, you may want to try switching your INNER joins to LEFT.  It should process much quicker.  If you need to filter out unanswered items, null users, etc., try doing so in the WHERE clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

Composite indexes needed:

```
survey_users:  (su_s_id, su_uid)
survey_topics:  (st_survey_id, st_id)
topic_questions:  (tq_st_id, tq_id)
a:  (sr_tq_id, sr_su_uid, sr_st_id)
```